Find exact and similar phrases in a string with millions of characters
I have a list of phrases and a corpus which is a string of text with millions of words. For each phrase in my phrase list, I want to find and record the most similar phrases found in the corpus-string.
For my purposes I need to use SBERT similarity, and found the sentence-transformers lib to the best.
My problem is that while there exists documentation for finding similarities between two lists, I couldn't find any for finding a list of phrases within a large string. I tried splitting my string into a list of sentence, but compute-time is incredibly long because for each phrase in the phrases list I need to loop thru each sentence (and there are plenty) and then append all matches to a dictionary I am creating. Additionly, the phrases from the phrase list are matched against the entire sentence (split from the string), but I am looking for any instance within the text, even one or two words ( or conversely multiple sentences) that are similar to my phrase.
phrase_list = ['Gregor Samse', 'in his bed into', 'horrible creature'...] # mine has 156 phrases

very_long_string= 'One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin. He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a little he could see his brown belly, slightly domed and divided by arches into stiff sections. The bedding was hardly able to cover it and seemed ready to slide off any moment. His many legs, pitifully thin compared with the size of the rest of him, waved about helplessly as he looked...' 
# mine has around 11 million words 

# convert text corpus string to list of sentences
string_to_sent_list = very_long_string.split(".")

from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, util

model = SentenceTransformer('all-mpnet-base-v2')


phrase_embeddings = model.encode(phrase_list, convert_to_tensor=True)
sent_embeddings = model.encode(string_to_sent_list, convert_to_tensor=True)

similarity_dict = {}
for i, phraselist_phrase in enumerate(phrase_list):
    similarities = util.cos_sim(phrase_embeddings[i], sent_embeddings)
    matches = [string_to_sent_list[j] for j, sim in enumerate(similarities[0]) if sim > 0.65] 
    similarity_dict[phraselist_phrase] = matches

print(similarity_dict)

similarity_dict.to_csv('similarity dict.csv')

Are there alternative ways to accomplish this, either thru looping in a different way or using a different library? Open to any ideas. My goal is very simply to save all the corresponding phrase-matches within the corpus for each phrase in my phrase list.
P.S. Anyone know if this method saves as a match multiple version of the same phrase for example, for phrase 'must complete this' would it consider 'we must complete this project', and 'we must' , 'must complete', 'complete this' as matches even-tho they are from the same sentence?

other than raising my similarity threshold...

Edited my question, but I am assuming this library also finds semantically similar phrases or partial matches, correct? Like 'horrible creature' would match with 'horrible vermin'

for the phrases_list min length is two words and max is seven words. For the sentences list the max is more... not sure exactly, maybe 30 words

See Rabin-Karp algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm

You can use a set of algorithms to solve this problem. Of course, since the problem is complicated, the solution is also complex.

First break both your string and phrases into words and record the indices. Now you have both of them as words.

Loop through words of phrases and words of string, and check if you have an exactly similar word. If you do, then you "may" have a possible output within a close window of string. Here, you can create a window, and see if your phrase is in the window, "exactly" or "partially". For "partially" you can use Levenshtein, and for "exact" you can use KMP.


I did not code the whole algorithm, will take you some time to do so. Partially, I did though, and you can do the rest.
import re, string, collections


def _matches(s, p):
    return [(match.group(0), match.start(), match.end()) for match in re.finditer(p, s)]


def get_lps(p):
    lps, j = [0] * len(p), 0
    for i in range(1, len(p)):
        while j and p[i] != p[j]:
            j = lps[j - 1]
        if p[i] == p[j]:
            j += 1
        lps[i] = j
    return lps


def kmp(s, p):
    lps, indices, j = get_lps(p), [], 0
    for i in range(len(s)):
        while j and s[i] != p[j]:
            j = lps[j - 1]
        if s[i] == p[j]:
            j += 1
        if j == len(p):
            indices.append(i - len(p) + 1)
            j = lps[j - 1]
    return indices


def levenshtein_edit_distance(A, B):
    dp = [[0] * (len(B) + 1) for _ in range(len(A) + 1)]
    for i in range(len(A) + 1):
        dp[i][0] = i
    for j in range(len(B) + 1):
        dp[0][j] = j

    for i in range(1, len(A) + 1):
        for j in range(1, len(B) + 1):
            if A[i - 1] == B[j - 1]:
                dp[i][j] = dp[i - 1][j - 1]
            else:
                dp[i][j] = 1 + min(dp[i - 1][j - 1], dp[i - 1][j], dp[i][j - 1])

    return dp[-1][-1]


phrase_list = ['Gregor Samse', 'in his bed into', 'horrible creature']

phs = list(set(phrase_list))
s = ' ' * 50 + \
    """
One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin. 
He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a little he could see his brown belly, slightly domed and divided by arches into stiff sections. The bedding was hardly able to cover it and seemed ready to slide off any moment. 
His many legs, pitifully thin compared with the size of the rest of him, waved about helplessly as he looked...""" \
+ ' ' * 50
p = r'(?:\b[^\r\n\s\t,?:;\'"!_-]+?\b)'

s_matches = _matches(s, p)
print(s_matches)

d = {ph: _matches(ph, p) for ph in phs}
print(d)


res = []
possibles = collections.defaultdict(list)
for k, val in d.items():
    for (word_a, st_a, end_a) in val:
        for (word_s, st_s, end_s) in s_matches:
            if word_a == word_s:
                search_window = s[st_s - 10:end_s + 10]
                found = kmp(search_window, word_a)[0]
                print(st_s, found, search_window)
                possibles[k] += [(st_s, found, search_window)]
                # break
print(possibles)


Levenshtein Distance
Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm

Similarity
Note that Levenshtein calculates the distance of two strings.

If their distance is 0, it is an exact match.
If their distance is close, it is a close match.
If their distance is not close, it is not a match.

def levenshtein_edit_distance(A, B):
    dp = [[0] * (len(B) + 1) for _ in range(len(A) + 1)]
    for i in range(len(A) + 1):
        dp[i][0] = i
    for j in range(len(B) + 1):
        dp[0][j] = j

    for i in range(1, len(A) + 1):
        for j in range(1, len(B) + 1):
            if A[i - 1] == B[j - 1]:
                dp[i][j] = dp[i - 1][j - 1]
            else:
                dp[i][j] = 1 + min(dp[i - 1][j - 1], dp[i - 1][j], dp[i][j - 1])

    return dp[-1][-1]


phrase = 'horrible creature'
s = 'horrible vermin'
dist = levenshtein_edit_distance(phrase, s)
if levenshtein_edit_distance(phrase, s) < len(phrase) // 2:
    print(f"'{s}' and '{phrase}' are similar matches with a character distance of {dist}.")

prints

'horrible vermin' and 'horrible creature' are similar matches with a
character distance of 7.

Additional Comments:

How does this scale to strings of millions of characters, though? (@tripleee)

KMP has a O(N + M) time complexity (N and M being the two lengths of strings). Levenshtein's time complexity is a bit higher, O (N * M). These algorithms are pretty much the fastest classic algorithms for string matching.

For applications, similar to the asked question, we don't seem to have many comparisons. We reduce the size of problem by first finding the core indices that we are interested to search around.

For more CPU and memory required applications, we would use Trie, sets and other suitable data structures, local and global caching (so that we won't need to visit every single pairs).


Rabin-Karp
For billions of comparison, we can also take advantage of Rolling Hash algorithms, with time complexity of O(N + M). However, hashing makes it slightly faster.
def rabin_karp(s, p, x=31):
    mod = 1_000_000_007
    if len(s) < len(p) or not p or not s:
        return []
    hs, hp = 0, 0
    for i in range(len(p)):
        hp *= x
        hp += ord(p[i])
        hp %= mod
        hs *= x
        hs += ord(s[i])
        hs %= mod
    indices = []
    hash = pow(x, len(p) - 1) % mod
    for i in range(len(s) - len(p) + 1):
        if hs == hp and s[i: i + len(p)] == p:
            indices.append(i)
        if i < len(s) - len(p):
            hs *= x
            hs -= x * ord(s[i]) * hash
            hs += ord(s[i + len(p)])
            hs += mod
            hs %= mod
    return indices

Boyer-Moore
Boyer-Moore is also certainly a good helper method for fast string matching, especially when it comes to suffixes and prefixes. It has an average time complexity of O(N + M).
Code from Wiki
from typing import *
# This version is sensitive to the English alphabet in ASCII for case-insensitive matching.
# To remove this feature, define alphabet_index as ord(c), and replace instances of "26"
# with "256" or any maximum code-point you want. For Unicode you may want to match in UTF-8
# bytes instead of creating a 0x10FFFF-sized table.

ALPHABET_SIZE = 26

def alphabet_index(c: str) -> int:
    """Return the index of the given character in the English alphabet, counting from 0."""
    val = ord(c.lower()) - ord("a")
    assert val >= 0 and val < ALPHABET_SIZE
    return val

def match_length(S: str, idx1: int, idx2: int) -> int:
    """Return the length of the match of the substrings of S beginning at idx1 and idx2."""
    if idx1 == idx2:
        return len(S) - idx1
    match_count = 0
    while idx1 < len(S) and idx2 < len(S) and S[idx1] == S[idx2]:
        match_count += 1
        idx1 += 1
        idx2 += 1
    return match_count

def fundamental_preprocess(S: str) -> list[int]:
    """Return Z, the Fundamental Preprocessing of S.

    Z[i] is the length of the substring beginning at i which is also a prefix of S.
    This pre-processing is done in O(n) time, where n is the length of S.
    """
    if len(S) == 0:  # Handles case of empty string
        return []
    if len(S) == 1:  # Handles case of single-character string
        return [1]
    z = [0 for x in S]
    z[0] = len(S)
    z[1] = match_length(S, 0, 1)
    for i in range(2, 1 + z[1]):  # Optimization from exercise 1-5
        z[i] = z[1] - i + 1
    # Defines lower and upper limits of z-box
    l = 0
    r = 0
    for i in range(2 + z[1], len(S)):
        if i <= r:  # i falls within existing z-box
            k = i - l
            b = z[k]
            a = r - i + 1
            if b < a:  # b ends within existing z-box
                z[i] = b
            else:  # b ends at or after the end of the z-box, we need to do an explicit match to the right of the z-box
                z[i] = a + match_length(S, a, r + 1)
                l = i
                r = i + z[i] - 1
        else:  # i does not reside within existing z-box
            z[i] = match_length(S, 0, i)
            if z[i] > 0:
                l = i
                r = i + z[i] - 1
    return z

def bad_character_table(S: str) -> list[list[int]]:
    """
    Generates R for S, which is an array indexed by the position of some character c in the
    English alphabet. At that index in R is an array of length |S|+1, specifying for each
    index i in S (plus the index after S) the next location of character c encountered when
    traversing S from right to left starting at i. This is used for a constant-time lookup
    for the bad-character rule in the Boyer–Moore string search algorithm, although it has
    a much larger size than non-constant-time solutions.
    """
    if len(S) == 0:
        return [[] for a in range(ALPHABET_SIZE)]
    R = [[-1] for a in range(ALPHABET_SIZE)]
    alpha = [-1 for a in range(ALPHABET_SIZE)]
    for i, c in enumerate(S):
        alpha[alphabet_index(c)] = i
        for j, a in enumerate(alpha):
            R[j].append(a)
    return R

def good_suffix_table(S: str) -> list[int]:
    """
    Generates L for S, an array used in the implementation of the strong good-suffix rule.
    L[i] = k, the largest position in S such that S[i:] (the suffix of S starting at i) matches
    a suffix of S[:k] (a substring in S ending at k). Used in Boyer–Moore, L gives an amount to
    shift P relative to T such that no instances of P in T are skipped and a suffix of P[:L[i]]
    matches the substring of T matched by a suffix of P in the previous match attempt.
    Specifically, if the mismatch took place at position i-1 in P, the shift magnitude is given
    by the equation len(P) - L[i]. In the case that L[i] = -1, the full shift table is used.
    Since only proper suffixes matter, L[0] = -1.
    """
    L = [-1 for c in S]
    N = fundamental_preprocess(S[::-1])  # S[::-1] reverses S
    N.reverse()
    for j in range(0, len(S) - 1):
        i = len(S) - N[j]
        if i != len(S):
            L[i] = j
    return L

def full_shift_table(S: str) -> list[int]:
    """
    Generates F for S, an array used in a special case of the good-suffix rule in the Boyer-Moore
    string search algorithm. F[i] is the length of the longest suffix of S[i:] that is also a
    prefix of S. In the cases it is used, the shift magnitude of the pattern P relative to the
    text T is len(P) - F[i] for a mismatch occurring at i-1.
    """
    F = [0 for c in S]
    Z = fundamental_preprocess(S)
    longest = 0
    for i, zv in enumerate(reversed(Z)):
        longest = max(zv, longest) if zv == i + 1 else longest
        F[-i - 1] = longest
    return F

def string_search(P, T) -> list[int]:
    """
    Implementation of the Boyer–Moore string search algorithm. This finds all occurrences of P
    in T, and incorporates numerous ways of pre-processing the pattern to determine the optimal
    amount to shift the string and skip comparisons. In practice it runs in O(m) (and even
    sublinear) time, where m is the length of T. This implementation performs a case-insensitive
    search on ASCII alphabetic characters, spaces not included.
    """
    if len(P) == 0 or len(T) == 0 or len(T) < len(P):
        return []

    matches = []

    # Preprocessing
    R = bad_character_table(P)
    L = good_suffix_table(P)
    F = full_shift_table(P)

    k = len(P) - 1      # Represents alignment of end of P relative to T
    previous_k = -1     # Represents alignment in previous phase (Galil's rule)
    while k < len(T):
        i = len(P) - 1  # Character to compare in P
        h = k           # Character to compare in T
        while i >= 0 and h > previous_k and P[i] == T[h]:  # Matches starting from end of P
            i -= 1
            h -= 1
        if i == -1 or h == previous_k:  # Match has been found (Galil's rule)
            matches.append(k - len(P) + 1)
            k += len(P) - F[1] if len(P) > 1 else 1
        else:  # No match, shift by max of bad character and good-suffix rules
            char_shift = i - R[alphabet_index(T[h])][i]
            if i + 1 == len(P):  # Mismatch happened on first attempt
                suffix_shift = 1
            elif L[i + 1] == -1:  # Matched suffix does not appear anywhere in P
                suffix_shift = len(P) - F[i + 1]
            else:               # Matched suffix appears in P
                suffix_shift = len(P) - 1 - L[i + 1]
            shift = max(char_shift, suffix_shift)
            previous_k = k if shift >= i + 1 else previous_k  # Galil's rule
            k += shift
    return matches


How does this scale to strings of millions of characters, though?
